# Filter out null character strings from string array

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I receive a json array of strings from an external source and some of my string look like

```
"\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00"
```

I would like to filter out all strings that only contain these null values. 
I've tried this

```
arr = arr.filter { (str: String) -> Bool in
            let invalid = String(data: Data.init(count: str.count), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print(str)

            return str == invalid
        }
```

Since these are all null terminators, i decided to create a null string of the same length as `str` but only containing null terminators and compare them.

But this doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure those are null terminators? It seems like the backslash character, followed by `x` followed by 2 zeros.

Comment: You are right. These are not null terminators. Not sure why i am getting that string for the external source. Guess i'd have to figure that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think those are null terminators because the backslashes are escaped. Those are just the four character sequence `\x00` repeated multiple times.

To match such a pattern, you can use regular expressions:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^(?:\\\\x00)+$", options: [])
let string = "\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00"
// the below will evaluate to true if the string is full of \x00
regex.firstMatch(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count)) != nil
```